# How to convert std::string::const_iterator type to int type in c++

Tags: c++

I am a newbie in C++

I want to use c++ to implement the string split function, so I wrote the following code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <regex>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

    std::string str = "1:2-3:4";
    std::smatch result;
    std::regex pattern("[:-]");

    std::string::const_iterator iterStart = str.begin();
    std::string::const_iterator iterEnd = str.end();


    std::vector<std::string> splitList = {};
    while (regex_search(iterStart, iterEnd, result, pattern))
    {
        // If std::string::const_iterator provides the int attribute
        // splitList.push_back(str.substr(iterStart.int, result[0].first.int));

        iterStart = result[0].second;
    }
```

The type of `result[0].first` is `std::string::const_iterator`, and the str.substr function requires parameters of type `int`, so I want to convert `result[0].first` to `int` Types of

Thanks for help.

Comment: You will want `do { regex_search(iterStart, iterEnd, result, pattern); /* your choice here */ iterStart = result[0].second; } while (iterStart != iterEnd);` or you will miss the last part of the pattern.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Yes, I have encountered this bug, and then I added `splitList.emplace_back(iterStart, iterEnd);` after the end of the loop

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). You don't want an int type, you want that substring, and you can get it through the iterators you have just fine. Like this:

```
splitList.emplace_back( iterStart, result[0].first );
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you are looking for something like [std::distance](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance)? Given a pair of iterators, it return the number of 'hops' needed to get from the first to the second. So

```
std::distance(iterStart, result[0].first)
```

will tell you the position (as an integer) of the result pointer inside your (current) string. You can then use that to extract the substring:

```
auto start = std::distance(str.begin(),iterStart);
auto len   = std::distance(iterStart, result[0].first);
auto sub_str = str.substr(start,len);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use str.begin(). The code below works:

```
    std::vector<std::string> splitList = {};
    while (regex_search(iterStart, iterEnd, result, pattern))
    {
        // If std::string::const_iterator provides the int attribute
        splitList.push_back(str.substr(iterStart - str.begin(), result[0].first - iterStart));

        iterStart = result[0].second;
    }
    if (iterStart != str.end())
    {
        splitList.push_back(str.substr(iterStart - str.begin(), result[0].first - iterStart));
    }
```